# Small confidence interval in polynomial regression

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, standard-error

I am studying the 7th chapter of Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R (ISLR) and I don't understand why the confidence interval associated with polynomial regressions (as seen in the first plot [here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/HumanitiesandScience/StatLearning/asset/ch7.html)) is so narrow.

According to the book (and to the R code provided), the dotted lines correspond to the predicted value, plus or minus twice the standard error - which, for normally distributed error terms, corresponds to ~95% confidence interval. However, according to the R code below (sorry it's so ugly), only 254 out of 3000 observations fall within the confidence interval:

```
library(ISLR)

age_range = range(Wage$age)
age.grid = seq(age_range[1], age_range[2])

fit = lm(wage~poly(age, 4), data=Wage)

preds = predict(fit, newdata=list(age=age.grid), se=TRUE)

within_interval = 0

for (i in 1:nrow(Wage)) {
    wage = Wage[i, "wage"]
    age = Wage[i, "age"]
    index = which(age.grid==age)
    pred = preds$fit[index]
    se = preds$se.fit[index]

    if (wage >= pred - 2*se & wage <= pred + 2*se) {
        within_interval = within_interval + 1
    }
}
```

So why does the model gives out such a narrow confidence interval? Are the errors not normally distributed, and is the confidence interval meaningless? (The residual plot does show a long right tail.) What am I missing here?

Comment: For a nice explanation of the meanings of the 95% confidence interval and prediction interval traces shown in a graph with a linear regression, see this two-minute video by Dr. Gerard Verschuuren: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXa_xhCtZ-U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse a *confidence interval*, a *quantile* and a *prediction interval*.

Your confidence interval is a CI for the conditional mean, that is, for an unobserved and unobservable parameter of the underlying distribution. Here is its interpretation: if your model is correct and you repeat your experiment many times (sampling data, fitting the model and calculating a CI anew each time), then 95% of your CIs will contain the true underlying conditional mean.

However, your actual *observations* are distributed around this conditional mean, and the width of the observations' distribution is governed by the residual noise. Therefore, there is no reason to expect a given CI-for-the-mean to contain any specific percentage of the actual observations.

Look at it this way: if you simulate more and more data with a given conditional mean and noise and fit your model, then the CI for the mean will get narrower and narrower the more data you simulate, because a larger sample size means that the mean can be estimated better and better. However, if your noise level doesn't change, then this CI will contain fewer and fewer actual observations.

A similar confusion often appears in prediction. You can predict the future expected value and also give a confidence interval for it. But what people are usually interested in is not a CI for the future mean (which is, again, unobservable anyway), but a *prediction interval* that will contain a prespecified percentage of future *observations*. PIs will typically be larger than CIs.

You may be interested in the `interval="prediction"` argument to `predict.lm()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stephen. There is a lengthy previous discussion in the book of the difference between confidence and prediction intervals, and I completely forgot about it.